# Find and delete text

Tags: vba, outlook, ms-word

I wrote code in Word to find "[edit]" links in a document, break the hyperlink, and delete the text.

I would like to adapt this to run in Outlook. I have gone to tools>references to allow Outlook to access Word object library, and inserted the following code before my "DeleteEditLinks" macro:

```vb
    Dim Ins As Outlook.Inspector
    Dim Document As Word.Document
    Dim Word As Word.Application
    Dim Selection As Word.Selection
    
    Set Ins = Application.ActiveInspector
    Set Document = Ins.WordEditor
    Set Word = Document.Application
    Set Selection = Word.Selection
```

The final code looks like this:

```vb
Public Sub DeleteEditLinks()
    Dim Ins As Outlook.Inspector
    Dim Document As Word.Document
    Dim Word As Word.Application
    Dim Selection As Word.Selection
    
    Set Ins = Application.ActiveInspector
    Set Document = Ins.WordEditor
    Set Word = Document.Application
    Set Selection = Word.Selection
    
    Dim oField As Field ' breaks hyperlinks of "[edit]" links, and deletes them
    For Each oField In ActiveDocument.Fields
        If oField.Type = wdFieldHyperlink Then
            If Left(oField.Result, 4) = "edit" Then
                oField.Unlink
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Set oField = Nothing
      
    Dim sample
    sample = "[edit]"
    
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = sample
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

How do I adapt this to run on the text of an Outlook email?

Comment: *How* does it "not work"? Certainly, at a glance, you need to replace `ActiveDocument` with `Document` (although I recommend you choose different vairable names for that an `Word` to ensure VBA doesn't confuse them with the keywords). Beyond that you need to tell us what errors you get and  on which lines or describe the desired and actual result of running the code.

Comment: *But this does not work*
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm not sure how Fields object must appear in the outlook, as well as what ecxatly you are trying to achieve, but!.. I've found basic issues in your code, so, my solution might be helpful.

- You refer to ActiveDocument within as it is a part of Outlook objects collection. It is not, so you need to refer to the Document object which you've correctly created from inspector. The same with Selection.
- I used late binding (Dim oField As Object), not sure if with early binding and "tools>references" option on you also have this trouble, but word constants wdFindContinue were not recognized so I used values for them (just googled them).

So, if in your target e-mails there are fields somehow - your updated code below should work... Please write if not the case.

```
Public Sub DeleteEditLinks()

Dim Ins As Outlook.Inspector
Dim Document As Object
Dim oField As Object
Dim sample As String

Set Ins = Application.ActiveInspector
Set Document = CreateObject("Word.Document")
Set Document = Ins.WordEditor

For Each oField In Document.Fields
  If oField.Type = 88 Then
    If Left(oField.Result, 4) = "edit" Then
      oField.Unlink
    End If
  End If
Next
Set oField = Nothing

sample = "[edit]"

Document.Application.Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Document.Application.Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting

With Document.Application.Selection.Find
    .Text = sample
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = 1
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .Execute Replace:=2
End With


End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome, this does exactly what I need and I understand where I went wrong. Sorry for not providing enough information up top, but you've helped tremendously.Thank you very much!